# How to ONLY target Chrome DevTools window in CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, customization, google-chrome-devtools

I came across [this thread](http://darcyclarke.me/design/skin-your-chrome-inspector/) a few days ago looking to get rid of the stark white background in the DevTools window. One thing led to another and I started in on adding rules for many more elements using the base CSS file (`chrome-devtools://devtools/devTools.css`) as a guide.

**The file being modified can be found in the following locations:**

**Mac:** `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css`

**PC:** `C:UsersYourUsernameAppDataLocalGoogleChromeUser DataDefaultUser StyleSheetsCustom.css`

**Ubuntu (Chromium):** `~/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css`

---

Midway through, I started running into a problem when modifying rules with very common selectors. The first two I ran into were `#main` and `#toolbar`. When adding rules for the more common selectors, if a web page is also using these same selectors (ie. google search), then the rules are applying to those pages or sites as well.

I understand why this is happening. My question is...

### Is there a way to only target the DevTools window in Chrome via this Custom.css file without affecting any other domain?

I've tried using the `@moz-document domain ()` and `@moz-document url-prefix ()`declarations but can't figure it out...

I'm too far in to give up now, so I'm hoping someone can assist.

---

Here is a screenshot of my progress so far: [image: Chrome DevTools Mod]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after digging around, I noticed I actually missed the notice right smack dab at the top of the original article page:

> Since publishing this article the Chrome Team have added a unique ID
>   to the container of the Chrome Dev Tools. The ID is `#-webkit-web-inspector`([Trac Reference](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/99933/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/inspector.html))

So, the fix to my above post is to add `body#-webkit-web-inspector` to all of your selectors and it works perfect, thus only targeting chromes DevTools window. Also, **very important**... to those wanting to create a more complete theme, it’s **HIGHLY RECOMMENDED** to do it via "inspecting the inspector". More info on how to do this can be found here: [How do you inspect the web inspector in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291138/how-do-you-inspect-the-web-inspector-in-chrome)

See screenshot below of "inspecting the inspector":
[image]