# How to add persudo elements in chorme developer tools?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, web

[console pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKeom.png)

I want to see what will happen when i add a ::hover persudo elements.How to make it in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question has already been asked and [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023952/how-do-i-add-insert-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-into-chromes-inspector). In short, you select the node in the Inspector and click the "+" sign under the styles tab to insert a new rule. Then, add a rule to style the psuedo element, e.g. `h2::after { content: ">>"; }`.

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, then flag it as such. Don't add another answer.