# Console.log without reference to the script

Tags: javascript, facebook, console.log

Pretty useless question, I guess, but it's really interesting to find out how facebook prints to browser console without reference to the script. Open the console at facebook.com and you will see text, but won't see the reference to th javascript...

[image]

Comment: You can override JS functions simply be redefining them. `console.log = function(){ /* whatever magic you want */ }`

Comment: yep, I can, but I just want to output text to console, but without reference. what should I override it to?

Comment: You might need to look into the source code of the dev tools console for that... You can right click and "inspect element" on the tool pane to learn more :)

Comment: you mean look in the sourcecode of the browser? because console.log is native browser function

Comment: No - not the browser souce - just the dev tools source. After all, it's that code that renders the console's output.

Comment: sorry, I can't get what you mean by saying 'inspect element on the toolpane' - how do I find code that renders to console?

Comment: @ProstoTrader It's not a useless question. Actually I am interested in the answer too..It's quite interesting how they did it.

Comment: @ProstoTrader - All you have to do is make sure that the dev tools are in a detached window and you can inspect the inspector :) Check out this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291138/how-do-you-inspect-the-web-inspector-in-chrome

Comment: wow! didn't know we can inspect the inspector )))
simply changing css we can hide reference )))

#console-messages .link, #console-messages a {
color: transparent;
cursor: pointer;
}

Comment: but that's not what facebook did - they don't have reference at all
probably they rewrited js...trying to find where it's hidden

Comment: @ProstoTrader Actually i dont know how did you get that message in your log above , normally when i log FB , my console is clear !!

Comment: @ProllyGeek You don't have to log in. Just go the fb url and inspect

Comment: well, it might depend on county I guess

Comment: @ProstoTrader no actually it really depends if you are logged in or not , after logging out , the message appeared in my console.

Comment: well, I'm logged and I see the message ))

Comment: @ProstoTrader from what i see it only happens with chrome , and the source is not shown , actually because chrome doesnt know what file produces this message (source file) proven when i awnt to filter the console , it shows filter from undefined !

Comment: @ProllyGeek - but HOW they hide the source file? I've tried searching all sources for the frase and it's not there....

Answer (score 7):

Well, friend of my friend found the answer.

To console.log without reference we should use setTimout and bind

```
setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, 'test'));
```

And here is the whole facebook snippet:

```
    var i = "Stop!",
        j = "This is a browser feature intended for developers. If someone told you to copy-paste something here to enable a Facebook feature or \"hack\" someone's account, it is a scam and will give them access to your Facebook account.";

if ((window.chrome || window.safari)) {
var l = 'font-family:helvetica; font-size:20px; ';
[
   [i, l + 'font-size:50px; font-weight:bold; ' + 'color:red; -webkit-text-stroke:1px black;'],
   [j, l],
   ['', '']
].map(function(r) {
    setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, '\n%c' + r[0], r[1]));
});
}
```

Comment: wow ! this is really unexpected , wonder why facebook devs did so though ?

Comment: I can understand why, but I can't really understand how they got to it.
Probavly one of them worket on webInspector previously and knew that bug

Comment: `if ((window.chrome || window.safari))` is useless because it works for example also on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

More generic function.
If run with () instead of ("Your title here","Your text here")
it will display the default message.

```
((title,message)=>{
    var i = title || "Stop!"
      , j = message || "This is a browser feature intended for developers. If someone told you to copy-paste something here to enable a Facebook feature or \"hack\" someone's account, it is a scam and will give them access to your Facebook account.";

    var l = 'font-family:helvetica; font-size:20px; ';
    [[i, l + 'font-size:50px; font-weight:bold; ' + 'color:red; -webkit-text-stroke:1px black;'], [j, l], ['', '']].map(function(r) {
        setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, '\n%c' + r[0], r[1]));
    });
})("Your title here","Your text here")
```

or directly:

```
console.alert = function(title, message) {
  var i = title || "Stop!",
    j = message || "This is a browser feature intended for developers. If someone told you to copy-paste something here to enable a Facebook feature or \"hack\" someone's account, it is a scam and will give them access to your Facebook account.";

  var l = 'font-family:helvetica; font-size:20px; ';
  [
    [i, l + 'font-size:50px; font-weight:bold; ' + 'color:red; -webkit-text-stroke:1px black;'],
    [j, l],
    ['', '']
  ].map(function(r) {
    setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, '\n%c' + r[0], r[1]));
  });
}
```

and

```
console.alert("Hello", "You can write what you like here!")
```

Comment: not working in angular 10 and may be back and above versions