# JqueryFile Upload direct to S3 doesn't work on CircleCi

Tags: amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload, circleci

I followed this instruction "https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails" to implement the "Upload file to S3 directly using Jquery-FileUpload"

It works perfectly in my localhost, but somehow it doesn't work on CircleCi . It always jump to the "fail" callback of Jquery-Fileupload without any specific error message

I already config the CORS configurations on AWS to allow "*" origin , which should works fine on all hosts ( and it does work on my localhost and my production server, but it still doesn't work on Circle CI )

Anybody experienced with it please guide me through this, biggest appreciation for any kind of help ( i can buy you a beer if you're in Vietnam :) )

Best regards

Comment: What is the error that you see in say [Chrome Inspector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291138/how-do-you-inspect-the-web-inspector-in-chrome) ? If there is none, what it the message/data in your `fail` callback?

Comment: Hi TJ, The error message is "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." , but with the same AWS configuration works in localhost, just doesn't work on CIRCLECI

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the CircleCI devs. Would you mind sending an in-app message about this, just hit the blue question mark in a circle at the lower-right.

That way I'll be able to see what your build is actually doing and I can discuss actual details of your build without worrying about revealing what's probably private information.

You can absolutely update this post afterwards once we've found a solution, that lets you can redact whatever you feel the need to redact (or nothing at all!)