# Editing the Google Chrome Developer Tools Itself

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

One day I was looking at the Google Chrome Developer, and I was accidentally holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scrolling the <kbd>mousewheel</kbd>, when, **bang** –

[image]

So, does that mean that the Google Chrome Developer Tools are **not** part of the standard Google Chrome interface? Is the Google Chrome Developer Tools a webpage itself? Do I need a Google Chrome Developer Tools for the Google Chrome Developer Tools?

> Dum dum dummmmmm

Anyway, so making the assumption that the Google Chrome Developer Tools is a **webpage**, then how can I access *it*? Where is the file holding it? How could I create my own version of the Google Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: this might answer some of your questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291138/how-do-you-inspect-the-web-inspector-in-chrome

Comment: @NoamHacker, yes! That's awesome!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you inspect the web inspector in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291138/how-do-you-inspect-the-web-inspector-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the link below contains all information for someone who would want to hack,debug or modify the  Chrome developer tools. The document quotes quite nicely somewhere "You can inspect the inspector.".

I believe this document does not have the ultimate latest data but it's relevant to the question above. I tried out the initial steps mentioned above and they worked fine.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WNF-KqRSzPLUUfZqQG5AFeU_Ll8TfWYcJasa_XGf7ro

Comment: Okay, this is really helpful! Just two things: firstly, add a little more information _about_ the answer in the answer, for future visitors etc. and secondly, delete your other answer. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: He meant answer. You said "Done", you deleted your other answer but you didn't edit this one until now. In general you shouldn't be posting multiple answers, you should be editing them.

Comment: Yes i understood and edited it right away. Thank you

Comment: @ketanShah, great! Thanks! :)