# Step forward N number of times in Javascript debugger in Chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I hate having to repeatedly press "step forward" in Chrome's Javascript debugger. I've had skip forward at least 100 times on this one script I am working on. How can I make it step forward any number of times I want it to before it pauses execution once more?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting a breakpoint?

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en

Comment: No, because I need to find the correct place first, which is why I need to step forward N times.

Comment: Not sure what the scenario you are trying to debug but conditional breakpoint should allow you to set it to the point you want to stop.

Answer (score 0):

As Dror mentioned, there are probably better ways to go about this.

However, if you really need the step forward functionality...

DevTools is a web app that you can inspect like any other page. [Open the inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291138/how-do-you-inspect-the-web-inspector-in-chrome) and then paste this code in the console:

```
var times = 4;
step()
function step(){
   var btn = document.querySelector(".scripts-debug-toolbar").shadowRoot.querySelector(".step-over-toolbar-item");
    var enabled = !btn.parentNode.disabled
   if (enabled ){
     btn.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {bubbles: true}));
     times--;
     if (times === 0){return}
     setTimeout(step, 1)
   } else {console.log("disabled");  setTimeout(step, 1) }
}
```

This will click on the "step over" button as many times as defined in the `times` varible.