# Confused on responsive design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm using Bootstrap to create my portfolio but I'm a bit confused when it comes to  Chrome's inspector tool.

See the photos below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Trnp.jpg

The first is resizing the browser which works fine  and looks nice. The second is using the chrome inspector tool for iPhone 5 and it just looks.. too small? The third is normal desktop.

Am I overthinking this or is Chrome not rendering it correctly when it comes to the inspector tool? The span for the navigation isn't their either.

Bear in mind this is just viewing from a file on my desktop, not on a server/framework yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it is hard to judge where the problem may lie.
However, there are a few ways you might find out for yourself, if it is not rendered correctly or there is a problem within your codebase.
1) Use the inspector tool in Google Chrome (or most other modern browsers), to find out what is causing the gap. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291138/how-do-you-inspect-the-web-inspector-in-chrome) for detailed steps how to do that.
2) Use other tools to simulate an iphone and see if the problem persists. For example [here](http://troy.labs.daum.net/), [here](http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/) or [here](http://ipadpeek.com/). 
3) Test on a real device. If that is not possible use a test lab. For Samsung devices you could use [this website](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action), for iPhone I am just aware of [this not free option](http://www.keynote.com/solutions/testing/mobile-testing). Otherwise you can see, if you can find a real device near you, using [this website](http://opendevicelab.com/).
I hope this gives you enough tools to solve the problem.