# Advanced styling of browser console.log

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools, console.log, devtools

The output of `console.log` can be styled and the basics are covered at the StackOverflow question [Colors in JavaScript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console).

#### Basic Styling

```js
console.log('%c Oh my heavens! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
```

[image]

#### Advanced Styling

What about advanced styles? How far can `console.log` be styled?

<s>How about images? Using `background-image` doesn't seem to work.</s>

How about `display: block`? It seems that setting `display: block` has no effect.

How about custom fonts? `font-family` seems to work but how to use custom fonts?

For my use case, I only need Chrome support.

#### Edit

I managed to implement images. The trick is to use a padding to set the size of the image. For example:

```js
var style = [
  'background-image: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/3o85xoi6nNqJQJ95Qc/giphy.gif")',
  'background-size: contain',
  'background-repeat: no-repeat',
  'color: #000',
  'padding: 20px 20px',
  'line-height: 0px'
  ].join(';');
console.log('%c ', style);
```

#### Edit 2

Firefox blocks external images in console styles, but supports dataURIs: https://bugzil.la/1134512. Also, Firefox let's you simply `display: block` entries, see the [list of properties supported by Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#Styling_console_output).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write#styling_console_output_with_css

Comment: @ArthurRubens I know about this but it is, unfortunately, nowhere close to a full spec.

Comment: You can inspect the source code of devtools frontend, it's in JS.

Comment: @wOxxOm Do you mean reading the source code of Chromium, or inspecting the DOM of the console? I'd love to insepct the DOM and I tried but didn't get there. Thanks!

Comment: You can do both. For the second thing see [How do you inspect the web inspector in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12291138)

Comment: Note (to self): Firefox blocks external images in console styles, but supports dataURIs. https://bugzil.la/1134512 (Also, Firefox let's you simple `display:block` entries.)

Comment: Also note MDN has nice list of *properties usable along with the `%c` syntax **at least in Firefox** browser* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#Styling_console_output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23320779/10002142 
This might help.

Answer (score 12):

[Chrome / Chromium seems to allow CSS properties beginning with any of the following prefixes](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/5165a7a61b1d10354d560dc72dc6409bf21ea5ae/front_end/console/ConsoleViewMessage.js#L895-L907):

- `background`
- `border`
- `color`
- `font`
- `line`
- `margin`
- `padding`
- `text`
- `-webkit-background`
- `-webkit-border`
- `-webkit-font`
- `-webkit-margin`
- `-webkit-padding`
- `-webkit-text`

For completeness' sake, [@myf has already linked to the properties supported by Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793376/advanced-styling-of-browser-console-log#comment111113530_62793376). They are:

- `background` and its longhand equivalents.
- `border-radius`
- `border` and its longhand equivalents
- `box-decoration-break`
- `box-shadow`
- `clear` and float
- `color`
- `cursor`
- `display`
- `font` and its longhand equivalents
- `line-height`
- `margin`
- `outline` and its longhand equivalents
- `padding`
- `text-*` properties such as text-transform
- `white-space`
- `word-spacing` and word-break
- `writing-mode`

Comment: Neat, thanks for the link to the source code, very helpful.