# Disable element highlighting on mouseover in elements tab of google-chome-devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I would like to disable the highlighting of elements/its bounding box when I hover/mouse over an element in the Elements tab of the dev tools.
On huge element trees (>3000 elements) the function is tremendously slow and resource consuming.

Answer (score 0):

**There's no such option.**

Workaround 1: disable the extended tooltip in devtools options

[image]

Workaround 2: disable the overlay by running the following command in console of [devtools-on-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12291163), which will work only in current tab's devtools until devtools is closed

- New Chrome: `[...UI.panels.elements.treeOutlines][0].highlightTreeElement=()=>{}`
- Old Chrome: `SDK.targetManager.models(SDK.OverlayModel)[0]._overlayAgent.highlightNode=async ()=>{}`

Comment: none of these works

Comment: The first workaround doesn't disable the overlay, it just makes it faster. The second workaround depends on the source code of devtools which constantly changes in Chrome, I've updated it for the current version.