# Can't right-mouse-click in chrome extension devtools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Chrome extension, that runs (and displays) inside the Chrome dev-tools. (known as [Extending DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/devtools/))

I upgraded to version 97.0 of Chrome and since then, whenever I try to right click the mouse from inside the extension, nothing happens.

I need the right click in order to inspect my extension.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Edit:
This question is not a duplicate of other suggested questions. Although the accepted solution to this problem is the same as other suggested question, the cause of this problem is different. The problem of my question is that since version 97 of chrome, right click is disabled in some devtools-extensions. As pointed out by @wOxxOm, this problem is caused by this [bug](https://crbug.com/1285312), whereas in other questions the poster directly wanted to know "how to inspect the devtools".

Comment: i have the same problem...

Comment: It's a [bug](https://crbug.com/1285312). Meanwhile, open [devtool-on-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12291163), then press Ctrl-Shift-C and select your panel.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @idoco for helping.

A nice workaround is to:

1. Open dev tools
2. **Undock** into separate window
3. Press **option+cmd+i** on the mac keyboard.

An explanation to why this issue happens can be found here:
https://microsoftedge.github.io/edgevr/posts/attacking-the-devtools/

Comment: That old article is about a different problem, which was fixed in 2020. The right-click bug was introduced in [October 2021](https://crrev.com/c/3223130).

Comment: ++ It doesnt seem working for me, what this does is just "open the DevTools on the DevTools", not really same as right click (though you do can right click on the new window...). ++ As a current workaround, you may just **click the `...` on the left of the element**... Or **`F2` if you want to just edit html** of the element.