# How can I debug the background page in a Chrome devtools extension?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a Chrome DevTools extension, and I can't find how to debug a script running in the background page.

I declared a DevTools background page in `manifest.json`:

```json
"devtools_page": "devtools-background.html"
```

That HTML page runs a script:

```html
<script src="devtools-background.js"></script>
```

The script adds a panel:

```js
chrome.devtools.panels.create('My Extension', '', 'index.html')
```

I can run my extension by opening DevTools on any page, and that works great, I see the panel. I can debug my panel's Elements and Scripts by opening the DevTools on the DevTools page (or going through `chrome://extensions` developer mode). I can even connect an external debugger from VS Code to the extension panel.

But I can't connect a debugger to the `devtools-background.js` from the background page. I can't use `console.log` or step debugging to understand what's going on in the background. The only thing I have is Errors from the `chrome://extensions` developer mode if an error occurs in that script. But no console or debugger.

Comment: Open devtools for the panel, then go to Sources: https://puu.sh/IFJAo/dfbedcba5e.png

Comment: Strangely that doesn't work when I start Chrome with `--load-extension` in the command line.

Comment: Works for me, but there's a bug in stable Chrome so just open devtools-on-devtools [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291138/how-do-you-inspect-the-web-inspector-in-chrome).

Comment: Thanks, it worked in the end.

Answer (score 2):

When you click "service worker", you can find background of console log.

[image]