# How to debug a service worker and a DevTools panel scripts in a Chrome extension?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to update my Chrome extension both to make it compatible with Manifest v.3 and to use a service worker and my own DevTools panel.
I declare both the service worker script and my DevTools panel page in `manifest.json`:

```
"background": { "service_worker": "myextension.js" },
"devtools_page": "devtools.myextension.html"
```

The Devtools panel page `devtools.myextension.html` contains the single line:

```
<script src="devtools.myextension.js"></script>
```

Script `devtools.myextension.js` contains the code:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create(
    "My Extension",
    "myextension.png",
    "panel.devtools.myextension.html",
    panel => {
        console.log("devtools.myextension.js");
    }
);
```

Service worker script `myextension.js` starts with the line:

```
console.log("myextension.js");
```

As it was advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661243/how-to-debug-chrome-devtools-panel-extension) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70906055/how-can-i-debug-the-background-page-in-a-chrome-devtools-extension) I open the DevTools for the service worker in a separate window, then find the tab with my DevTools panel (it is created successfully), and then open another DevTools on the DevTools panel in another separate window.
I can see both scripts mentioned above somewhere in the opened panels, I can see their logs in console(s), I can even mark some lines in those scripts as breakpoints.

The problem is those breakpoints never work. Is there a way to debug the code here normally rather than just to wait for error messages after its corrections?

Comment: I guess the "Disable breakpoints"  button is pressed? https://puu.sh/J6jef/ff56bfa848.png

Comment: @wOxxOm, it is not, of course. Moreover, breakpoints in a message listener, added, say, in the service worker, work as they should.  I guess the problem arises because each of these scripts initially always runs when its corresponding DevTools window is not opened yet. Maybe it can be considered even just a bug in Chrome, I do not know.

Comment: I guess you can reload the extension on chrome://extensions page without closing devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm, it works for the service worker, thank you. But it seems that it is not possible to debug the panel creation script `devtools.myextension,js` in this way, I could only use `console.debug(...)` to understand what specifically did go on in this script. Any other suggestion?

Comment: You can open a [devtools-on-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12291138), then press F5 or Ctrl-R in that new window.

Comment: @wOxxOm, unfortunately your solution doesn't work for me. When I press F5 in the devtools-on-devtools window, the window is reloaded, but I get the message `Error: timed out fetching locale at devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools-frontend/front_end/core/i18n/i18n.js:1:1622` and I do not see my files in source list anymore.

Comment: @wOxxOm, otherwise, if I press F5 on the initial DevTools panel and then go to the secondary one, I get the repeating message `Error: Readers took over 1500ms. Possible deadlock? at devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools-frontend/front_end/ui/components/render_coordinator/render_coordinator.js:1:238`