# How to suppress "Readers took over 1500ms. Possible deadlock?" exception in DevTools-on-DevTools for a custom DevTools panel in my Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

To debug scripts in my extension's custom DevTools panel I open another DevTools window over this panel, as it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72652260/how-to-debug-a-service-worker-and-a-devtools-panel-scripts-in-a-chrome-extension). Then I return to my DevTools panel, and then, say, go to read documentation in another window of another browser.

In this case both my DevTools windows are paused on promise rejection after a while, and I can see the message:

```
Exception: Error: Readers took over 1500ms. Possible deadlock?
           at devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools-frontend/front_end/ui/components/render_coordinator/render_coordinator.js:1:2388
```

The same exception/message occur in some other cases, when I do not work with my DevTools panel. Is there a way to suppress this exception, keeping in mind that I can not change built-in Chrome `render_coordinator.js` JS library?