# Inspecting Firefox's Web Inspector

Tags: firefox, web-inspector, rgba

Is it possible to inspect Firefox's Web Inspector? I know it's [possible to do so in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291138/how-do-you-inspect-the-web-inspector-in-chrome). I need to do so in Firefox so that I can obtain the RGBA values for their Margin, Border, Padding and Content sections of their Box Model Tool (see screenshot).

[image: Firefox's Box Model Tool]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1608642) outlined how to inspect Firefox's Web Inspector with their [Browser Toolbox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_toolbox/index.html) feature.

I also collated the relevant CSS that informs Firefox's Box Model if anyone else is interested:

```
:root {
  --grey-40: #b1b1b3;
  --grey-50: #737373;
  --grey-70: #38383d;

  --theme-sidebar-background: white;

  --marginbox-color: #fdffdf;
  --borderbox-color: var(--grey-50);
  --paddingbox-color: #e3dcff;
  --contentbox-color: #cff0fb;
  --marginbox-border-color: #d8e60a;
  --contentbox-border-color: #54a9ff;
  --position-border-color: var(--grey-50);
}

:root.theme-dark {
  --theme-sidebar-background: #18181a;

  --marginbox-color: #73764a;
  --borderbox-color: var(--grey-70);
  --paddingbox-color: #6657a6;
  --contentbox-color: #407aa4;
  --marginbox-border-color: #bdca00;
  --contentbox-border-color: #00b8ff;
  --position-border-color: var(--grey-40);
}

.boxmodel-margins {
  border-color: var(--marginbox-color);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 22px;
  outline: dashed 1px var(--marginbox-border-color);
}

.boxmodel-borders {
  border-color: var(--borderbox-color);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.boxmodel-paddings {
  border-color: var(--paddingbox-color);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 27px;
}

.boxmodel-contents {
  height: 18px;
  outline: dashed 1px var(--contentbox-border-color);
  background-color: var(--contentbox-color);
}
```