# How(Where) to get the these icons of Chrome Developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, chrome-devtools-protocol

[image]

I want to get these SVG icons for my purpose of use, How (or Where) I can get them? Is there a Chromium repo or something

Comment: The Chromium repo is here: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [devtools-on-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12291138) to inspect the UI of devtools and then search the [source code](https://source.chromium.org/).
The icons: https://crsrc.org/third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/Images/src/largeIcons.svg