# Scope section in Chrome DevTools is stuck at "Loading..."

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

When adding a breakpoint to a file within the Google Chromes Dev Tools "Sources" tab, the "Scope" section in the right hand column is suppose to get populated with all the available variables / objects declared in that file.

This functionality works as expected for some of my files, but for others it just displays this "Loading..." text.

Why is this?

[image]

Comment: It may be a bug in devtools. Check the console of [devtools-on-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12291138).

Comment: Try adding a delay in your code using the setTimeout() method

Comment: it happened to me just now 20 minutes after I'm already debugging the same component, for absolutely no reason. I've started a bounty here to hopefully get an answer

Comment: @TzachiElrom If you are looking for a quick fix, restarting chrome has been working for me

Comment: @scottc11 thanks but I want to know why this happens and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, reloading devtools fixed it for me.
To reload devtools, press Ctrl+Shift+P and search for "Reload Devtools" or Alt + R
[image]